# Manipulating Dirichlet characters and L functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions, number-theory

I read some basic knowledge about characters and L functions, and would like to play around with them in MMA.

I tried to do the following things, but ending in minor success. (MMA notation used)

1. Given a character modulo $k$, determine which index belongs to it.
   For example, we know that $\chi_{7,2}\chi_{7,3}$ is also a charactor, which turns out to be $\chi_{7,4}$. I assume that the index $j$ is ordered without a specific rule.
2. Given the character $\chi_{k,j}$, we know that it can be written as $\chi_{k,j}=\chi_{d,i}\chi_{k,1}$ for some $i$ such that $\chi_{d,i}$ is primitive, where $d$ is its conductor. How to find $d$ and $i$?
3. Given an L function $L(k,j,s)$, one can simplify it to smaller $k$ whenever the character is not primitive. How can we program to do this? In addition, the derivative w.r.t $s$ at certain values admit simplified forms, such as $
    \partial_s L_{6,2}(s)|_{s=-3}=-\frac{729 \sqrt{3} L_{3,2}(4)}{8 \pi ^3}$
   However, MMA fails to simplify the closed form directly, or even evaluating the numerical value. (It can, afterall, be evaluated after applying FunctionExpand ) Although we can always convert L functions to Hurwitz zeta and use their identities, the reduction of L functions comes in a fairly simpler way.

Of course, since we are dealing with a finite number of characters, comparing them one by one by brute force is apparently a way out, which, however, is not satisfactory to me.

**Question** Can we do (part of) the previous in an elegant way (perhaps with some advanced theories assisting)? Or, are there any packages available for doing those?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question and include Mathematica _code_ that you used.

Comment: My question is about realizing what I want to do in Mathematica. Why would I ask if I already have the code?

Comment: In your question, you wrote: _"I tried to do the following things ..."_ and _"MMA fails to simplify the closed forms ..."_ This clearly means you did some coding, right? So please include this in the question.